# Approval Workflow and a Task

Tags: workflow, approval

I used the built in approval workflow within SharePoint 2010 for a customized form created from InfoPath. Works perfectly, then I created a serparte workflow to assighn a task to users once the form has been approved. The problem is no matter what conditions and logic I make for this new form to ONLY assighn the task when approved it also assighns it when rejected. Any suggestions ? ( Tried various Else " stop workflow" or Else " if status = rejected, then stop workflow and still not working)

Step 1:
`If (JOB Form):ApprovalStatus equals );#Approved
   Wait for the Approval Status to equal 0;#Approved
Then Assighn Take A to Deborah`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need an "**else**" clause to finish your step.

```
IF "ApprovalStatus" equals "approve"

Then "assign task" to "Deborah"

ELSE "stop workflow"
```

Otherwise, it doesn't know what to do if your form is rejected, so it defauts to assigning.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Unfortunatly I tried that various times with different wording and still not budging.

Comment: Oh dear. Sorry I wasn't more help!